# Using PHP, can I put variables inside of variables?

Tags: php

For example, take this code:

```
$ch = curl_init($resultSet['url']."?get0=get0&get1=".$get1."&get2=".$get2."&get3=".$get3);
```

This of course, looks very ugly, and kind of a pain in the ass to read. So my question is, would I be able to use something like this:

```
$allgets ="?act=phptools&host=".$host."&time=".$duration."&port=".$port;
$ch = curl_init($resultSet['url'] . $allgets);
```

Very simple question I suppose, but my server is undergoing maintenance, so I can't upload it and test it myself. I suppose a yes or no answer will suffice, but if you have a more efficient way of doing this, that would be even better. :)

Comment: please use urlencode() to secure your variable values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definitely, it's just string concatenation.

You could also take a look at string [variable parsing](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing) if you want it to be "less messy".

Answer (score 0):

Your example might not work depending on the value of the variables because you didn't use URL-encoding.

A better way is something like this,

```
$fields = array (
   'host' => $host,
   'port' => $port
);

$ch = curl_init($resultSet['url'] . '?' . http_build_query($fields));
```

Comment: I would go one further and use `http_build_url` as well then it would be easy to change things if the url needs changing

Comment: If url may contain query strings already, http_build_url() is definitely the way to go. However, it requires http extension, which is rarely installed on all the hosts I used.